# Cycle rank of a null graph

Tags: graph-theory

For the null graph N5, would the cycle rank be negative, since you have to add 4 edges for the graph to become a tree?

Comment: I guess that by "null" graph $N_5$ you mean the ***empty graphI*** $\overline{K_5}$ with $5$ vertices and no edges? The unusual term "null graph" has been used for the "graph" with no vertices.

Comment: By null graph, I mean the graph of 5 vertices and no edges

Answer (score 0):

The **cycle rank** of a graph $G$ is defined as the number of edges that need to be removed from $G$ to obtain the spanning forest of $G$.

$N_p$, the null graph on $p$ vertices, has $p$ connected components, each consisting of a single vertex.

[By most definitions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3043113/can-a-tree-graph-have-only-one-vertex-and-if-so-that-means-that-a-tree-graph-h#:%7E:text=For%20the%20former%3A%20yes%2C%20by,edge%20graph%20is%20a%20tree), a graph consisting of a single vertex is considered a tree.

Following this convention, the spanning forest of $N_p$ is its own spanning forest - we needn’t remove any edges to obtain a spanning forest from it, so its cycle rank is $0$.

The **cutset** rank of $G$ is the number of edges in a spanning forest of $G$. The number of edges in the spanning forest of $N_p$ (i.e., $N_p$ itself) is $0$, so its cutset rank is $0$.