# Can a tree graph have only one vertex? And if so, that means that a tree graph has at minimum one leaf?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, trees

Also, if the tree is two vertices connected by an edge, does the root count as a leaf too? Since it's also a vertex of degree one?

I've had trouble clarifying this online and from my textbook. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah
a graph only has one vertice is a tree
but only a tree with at least 2 vertices has a leaf

Answer (score 1):

For the former: yes, by most definitions, the one-vertex, zero-edge graph is a tree.

For the latter: yes, all vertices of degree 1 are leaves. In general, which node you call the "root" is pretty much arbitrary.

Comment: Ok thank you. My teacher wrote in her notes that it has at minimum one leaf and then wrote that it has two minimum elsewhere. Perhaps she meant to say one leaf minimum for our purposes.

Comment: @user3482749 it seems to me that OP meant in the second part a graph containing just 2 vertices connected by 1 edge: *the tree is two vertices connected by an edge.* Can you revise your answer in this sense?

Comment: @user376343 Ah, that's been edited since I answered. With that version, yes, that's a tree.

Comment: @user3482749 I would gladly upvote your answer but as it is, is not fully coherent.